# CSS Hover not working in a hierarchy of absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small prototype for a slider that can have multiple scenes, and where each scene can have multiple annotated steps. The user can switch between scenes my dragging the mouse up and down, and between steps in a scene by mouse scrolling. The code for a small prototype (tested in Chrome) can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/eoh59vs8/

HTML:

```html
<div id="storyContainer">
  <div class="sceneContainer">
      <div class="stepContainer">
         <img alt="Scene 1 - Step1" style="background-color: #014CB6"/>
         <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:20px; left:50px">111</a>
         <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:20px; left:120px">112</a>
      </div>
      <div class="stepContainer">
         <img alt="Scene 1 - Step2" style="background-color: #00bfff"/>
         <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:80px; left:50px">121</a>
         <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:80px; left:120px">122</a>
      </div>

      <div class="stepButtonsContainer">
         <span class="stepButton active"></span>
         <span class="stepButton"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sceneContainer">
    <div class="stepContainer">
        <img alt="Scene 2 - Step1" style="background-color: red"/>
        <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:150px; left:150px">211</a>
        <a class="annotationPoint" style="top:180px; left:180px">212</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#storyContainer {
  width: 1031px; height: 580px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.sceneContainer {
  border-bottom: solid black thin;
  position: relative;
}

.stepContainer {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0; left:0;
}

.stepContainer:first-of-type {
  opacity:1;
}

.annotationPoint {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.annotationPoint:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

The problem is that the annotations are not hoverable. When playing around a bit, it seems that the problem is coming from the fact that the annotations are contained in a hierarchy of absolutely positioned elements.

My first thought was (as mentioned multiple times on other, similar stackoverflow questions) is that there is some problem with z-indexes due to the fact that there are a lot of elements stacked on top of each other, but I wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the CSS for your `#storyContainer .sceneContainer > .stepContainer`. In here you have set `pointer-events: none;`, which disables mouse events for the div *and it's children*. Therefore the `a` elements are not firing hover events to the browser.

It doesn't appear to have any impact if you remove this CSS, but if you need that then you just need to reset it in the CSS for the `.annotationPoint`s and any other elements you want to click hover etc:

```
.annotationPoint
{
    pointer-events:initial;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoh59vs8/1/)